# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table. PG12

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 12:

```
CREATE TABLE w_table (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE l_table (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS identity,
    w_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES w_table(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (w_id, id),
    UNIQUE (w_id, id)
)PARTITION BY LIST (w_id);

CREATE TABLE t_table (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    w_id INT REFERENCES w_table(id) NOT NULL,
    l_id INT REFERENCES l_table(id) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (w_id,id),
    UNIQUE (w_id,id)
)PARTITION BY LIST (w_id);
```

And I'm getting:

```
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "l_table"
```

Can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because:

```
l_id INT REFERENCES l_table(id) NOT NULL,
```

is pointing at the l_id.id which is not a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` constraint by itself. The `PRIMARY KEY` is `(w_id, id)` so you need to `REFERENCE` that combination. The w_table.id reference works because w_table.id is the `PRIMARY KEY` for that table. FYI, `UNIQUE (w_id, id)` is redundant to `PRIMARY KEY (w_id, id)`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240160/postgresql-multiple-column-foreign-key save the day.